# Passing a hex string in a textbox.text property to BitConverter.GetBytes as hex in C#

Tags: c#, string, hex, bitconverter

I am reading values from sensors and receiving two 16 bit Hex values back in string format "417D" and "8380" for example.

I cannot seem to find a way in C# to parse the strings to split them up into a byte array ( 41,7D,83,80 ) preserving the hex number.

I then use the following to convert the IEEE754 number to a decimal to get the correct sensor reading value.

`txtFloatValue.Text = BitConverter.ToSingle(hex, 0).ToString();`

The code below works, but I need to pass the values as a hex array, not 0x417D8380.

```
byte[] hex = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x417D8380);
txtFloatValue.Text = BitConverter.ToSingle(hex, 0).ToString();
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.  I may be approaching this the wrong way, but the IEEE754 conversion works well.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are starting with and where you are trying to go, but you can parse a hex string with `int.Parse("417D", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);` You can then use `GetBytes` and `BitConverter` as in your second code snippet.

Comment: Hexadecimal is a **representation**. What do you mean by "preserving the hex number"? What _exactly_ is your question? _"How to convert two hexadecimal strings to a `single`"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your hex strings to ints and then use `BitConverter`. For example:

```
var i = int.Parse("417D8380", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
var single = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);   // 15.8446
```

Comment: Upvoted. The first line can also be written `var i = Convert.ToInt32("417D8380", fromBase: 16);`

Comment: When concatenating `"417D"` and `"8380"`, one must be aware of endianness, I suspect.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Absolutely. You can check [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx).